# working with cmvision/Blobs

Tags: ros, cmvision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I am trying to work with cmvision/Blobs topic "message" and when I use in my code cmvision/Blobs.x it gives me an error, can anyone please show me how to access the elements of Blobs (x,y in particular)?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include "cmvision/Blobs.h"
#include <turtlesim/Pose.h>

using namespace std;

ros::Publisher pub_msg;
geometry_msgs::Twist cmd_msg;
cmvision::Blobs lastobjectpose;
turtlesim::Pose lastFollowerPose;

void fblobCallback(cmvision::Blobs object_pose)
{
    lastobjectpose=object_pose;
}

void fposeCallback(turtlesim::Pose follower_pose)
{
    lastFollowerPose=follower_pose;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    //ROS Initialization
    ros::init(argc, argv, "follower_leader");
    ROS_INFO("Node follower_leader Connected to roscore");
    ros::NodeHandle n ("~");
    ros::Subscriber pose_sub_object = n.subscribe<cmvision::Blobs>("/blobs",1,fblobCallback);
    ros::Subscriber pose_sub_follower = n.subscribe<turtlesim::Pose>("follower_pose",1,fposeCallback);

    pub_msg = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("follower_velocity",1);
    ros::Rate rate(10);
    ROS_INFO("SPINNING @ 10Hz");
    
    while (ros::ok()){
        ros::spinOnce();
        double d = 0;
    d = sqrt(   pow(lastobjectpose.x-lastFollowerPose.x,2)
            + pow(lastobjectpose.y-lastFollowerPose.y,2) ) ;
    double dtheta = 0.0 ;
    if( d>0.01 ) {
        dtheta =   atan2(lastobjectpose.y-lastFollowerPose.y,
                 lastobjectpose.x-lastFollowerPose.x)
        - lastFollowerPose.theta ;
    }

    if(d>0.01){     
        cmd_msg.linear.x = 0.2*d;
        cmd_msg.angular.z = 4*dtheta;}else{cmd_msg.linear.x = 0;
        cmd_msg.angular.z = 0;}
    pub_msg.publish(cmd_msg);
        rate.sleep();
    } 

    ROS_INFO("ROS-Node Terminated\n");
}
```

And here is the error i receive when i do "catkin_make":

```
Base path: /home/ghanim/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ghanim/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ghanim/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ghanim/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ghanim/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ghanim/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/ghanim/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 18%] Built target colorgui
[ 25%] Building CXX object color_follower/CMakeFiles/color_follower_node.dir/src/color_follower_node.cpp.o
[ 31%] Built target follower_leader_node
[ 43%] Built target cmvision_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Built target cmvision_generate_messages_py
[ 75%] Built target cmvision_generate_messages_lisp
[ 75%] Built target cmvision_gencpp
[ 75%] Built target cmvision_generate_messages
[100%] Built target cmvision
/home/ghanim/catkin_ws/src/color_follower/src/color_follower_node.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/ghanim/catkin_ws/src/color_follower/src/color_follower_node.cpp:60:33: error: ‘cmvision::Blobs’ has no member named ‘x’
/home/ghanim/catkin_ws/src/color_follower/src/color_follower_node.cpp:61:39: error: ‘cmvision::Blobs’ has no member named ‘y’
/home/ghanim/catkin_ws/src/color_follower/src/color_follower_node.cpp:64:36: error: ‘cmvision::Blobs’ has no member named ‘y’
/home/ghanim/catkin_ws/src/color_follower/src/color_follower_node.cpp:65:39: error: ‘cmvision::Blobs’ has no member named ‘x’
make[2]: *** [color_follower/CMakeFiles/color_follower_node.dir/src/color_follower_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [color_follower/CMakeFiles/color_follower_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189846/working-with-cmvision/blobs/) by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-08-12**:
Please update your question with the error message you're getting, and the code that produces it.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-08-12**:
When adding code, please don't create an answer. I moved the code to your original question, and deleted the answer you created.

**Comment by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) on 2014-08-13**:
okay and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the cmvision/Blobs message structure:

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
uint32 image_width
uint32 image_height
uint32 blob_count
cmvision/Blob[] blobs
  string name
  uint32 red
  uint32 green
  uint32 blue
  uint32 area
  uint32 x
  uint32 y
  uint32 left
  uint32 right
  uint32 top
  uint32 bottom
```

When you access your cmvision::Blobs struct like so `pow(lastobjectpose.x-lastFollowerPose.x,2)`, you are implying that the Blobs message type has some `x` member. However, the x and y that you are looking for are in actuality in `lastobjectpose.blobs[some_index].x` and so it goes for y. Hence it might make sense for you to instead loop through `lastobjectpose.blobs`, using `lastobjectpose.blob_count` as your bound, i.e,

```
for (i = 0; i < lastobjectpose.blob_count; i++) {
  //Do your stuff.
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) with karma: 301 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) on 2014-08-13**:
Thanks very much it is compiling now, i have another question though how can I access the image_width and height ?

**Comment by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) on 2014-08-13**:
I'm not much of a C++ person, but I believe you can think of a message in your code as you do a struct. Since image_width and image_height are direct members of this message, you can write `lastobjectpose.image_width` and `lastobjectpose.image_height`, respectively.

**Comment by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) on 2014-08-13**:
thanks very much actually i have done this way and yeah it is working :)